# Find out Fixed Points

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

Consider a set $M$ of all possible square matrices of dimension $k$ over a finite field $F_p$. Consider a map $f$ defined on $M$ as $f(X)=X^2+C$ where $X \in M$ and C is an arbitrary fixed matrix from the set $M$.

It is worth mentioning that the operations addition and multiplication on M are over finite field $F_p$.

How to determine analytically the fixed points and periodic points of different period.

Answers even in case of $p=2$ is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started. $k=p=2$

$C=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right)$

no solutions.

$C=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$, 8 solutions: $X=C,\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right),I,\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right)$.

$C=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$ or $\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right)$, 2 solutions: $X=C,C+I$

$C=I$, 2 solutions: $X=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right)$

$C=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right)$, 2 solutions: $X=C,\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right)$.

I hope I have understood you correctly. The above does not look promising for a neat general solution!

Comment: See to get fixed points we need to solve the matrix equation $X^2-X+C=0$. We want X which is in $M$. Let me know how do we solve this equation.

Comment: The reason you have not got any complete answers after 3 hours is that no one can see an easy answer to the question. It is fairly easy to get an answer for a specific $C$ and $p$, but you are looking for a general solution. So the usual approach is to start by looking at some simple cases to see if there is a pattern. At the moment I cannot see one. What makes you think the question has an answer?

Comment: There should be a general method to solve such equation. As I can remember, it is called Discrete Algebraic Riccati Equation. I want a method to solve such equation in this specific context.